# Using Python's filter function

Tags: python, primes, lambda

Here are two seemingly equivalent versions of a function for filtering out the primes from a list of numbers.

**Version 1**

```
def prime (mylist):
        for i in range(2, 8):
            return filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, mylist)
```

**Version 2**

```
def prime2 (mylist):
    nums = mylist
    for i in range(2, 8): 
        nums = filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, nums)
    return nums

print prime([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])  
   >> [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
print prime2([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]) 
   >> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
```

Version 1 returns erroneous results. Why?

Comment: Not the answer, but... forget about `filter`. Use list comprehensions.

Comment: In version 1, your 'return' is covered by the for loop, so the loop is disturbed by the return statement at the very first time of the for-loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first version only tests `i == 2`. In other words, it only tests whether 2 is a factor, instead of testing all integers from 2 to 7 as you intended. This is why it will (correctly) filter out all even numbers but will (wrongly) leave the odd ones which are not prime, like 9 and 15. Try this to see it explicitly:

```
def prime (mylist):
    for i in range(2, 8):
        print i # added to make things explicit; it's not necessary
        return filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, mylist)

def prime2 (mylist):
    nums = mylist
    for i in range(2, 8):
        print i # added to make things explicit; it's not necessary
        nums = filter(lambda x: x == i or x % i, nums)
    return nums

print prime([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
>>> 2
>>> [2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
print prime2([2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
>>> 2
>>> 3
>>> 4
>>> 5
>>> 6
>>> 7
>>> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
```

Answer (score 1):

The first function returns in the first loop iteration, so you never test against i>2.